# How is "my" faster than "local" in Perl?

Tags: perl

Quoting from **[PerlMonks: The difference between my and local](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=94007)**,

> But in real life, they work virtually the same? Yes. Sort of. So when should you use them?
>
> **Use my when you can (it's faster than local) ...**

I know the lexical vs dynamic scoping difference between `my` and `local`, as discussed in **[this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129607/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-local-in-perl)**, but I am not sure why `my` is "faster".

**What exactly do we mean when we say that a `my` variable is faster than a `local` variable in Perl?**

Comment: Be a *local* hero - try to read *my* code.

Comment: Don't use local vs. my because one is faster than the other; use whatever is most correct for what you want to achieve (usually my).

Comment: In other words: don't just count the time a program takes to run, above all count the time it takes a programmer to debug and fix it.  The programmer is much more expensive than the computer running the program.

Comment: Thinking of programmer's time being more valuable than execution time is wrong. It is not the execution (CPU) time that it is to be compared with, but the application user's time that is wasted while the program works. And when a lot of people use some program, even slightest performance increase can save lot of human hours.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `local` on a variable means that its previous state needs to be pushed onto a stack somewhere and restored again when the local scope is exited. Using `my` on a variable simply creates an entirely new variable that shadows the previous variable with the same name -- the previous one is entirely untouched, and does not need to be saved anywhere. It is simply lying in wait when the local scope is exited and it is visible again.

This pushing/popping to a stack takes resources; there's a lot of work under the hood to ensure that this works properly. (Consider cases such as an exception being thrown while in local scope, or a signal handler being executed. I'm sure you can think of more.)

Besides being more efficient, using `my` is much more logical. As a programmer introducing a local variable $foo, you don't need to worry about the semantic reason for the previous version of $foo, what data might already be in it, or indeed if there *was* a $foo already created.  If sometime down the road the earlier declaration of $foo is removed, your `local $foo` code will break, but `my $foo` will be perfectly happy.  Be a good programmer and keep your code in well-encapsulated pieces, which means using lexical scoping as much as you can. It's quite possible to write a large application and never need variables of package/global scope at all, especially when you use well-designed OO classes.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: no, it uses a stack called the savestack

Comment: Specifically there is a "lexical scratch pad" which has already been allocated for each lexical scope that Perl puts the new lexical onto. When scope exits, the scratch pad goes away. Also, local() has to deal with the localization and restoration of individual hash and array elements (`local $h{key}`). Finally, tied variables are treated special by local, their FETCH and STORE methods are called when they are localized and restored. Anything having to even consider tying is slower because it has to check if a variable is tied.

Answer (score 13):

`local` is probably slower because of the need to save the old value, but the speed of `local` vs `my` should not come into the discussion at all.  The speed savings is minuscule:

```
           Rate local    my
local 7557305/s    --   -2%
my    7699334/s    2%    --
```

and the features of the two are radically different.  The results above come from the following benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

our $x;

my %subs = (
    local => sub {
        local $x = 42;
        return $x;
    },
    my => sub {
        my $x = 42;
        return $x;
    }
);

for my $sub (keys %subs) {
    print "$sub: ", $subs{$sub}(), "\n";
}

Benchmark::cmpthese -1, \%subs;
```

Comment: The speed difference would become much more apparent when you introduce some of the cases that Schwern described under my answer.