# How does the difference between "my" and "local" interact with symbolic references?

Tags: perl

Previously I read related content in the book of "Effective Perl Programming", but didn't really understand it. Today, I encountered a problem about this, as below code.

```
my $vname = "a";
my @a = qw(1 2 3);
local @array = @$vname; 
foreach(@array) { print "$_\n"; };
```

It output nothing. Then I modified this line:

```
local @a = qw(1 2 3);
```

Just replaced "my" with "local", then it works now. So I'd like to figure out what's the difference between them.

Comment: Try [perldoc here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the perldoc shows the essential difference from the compiler's perspective. Maybe I have to reread Perl book tonight.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603466/how-is-my-faster-than-local-in-perl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129607/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-local-in-perl

Answer (score 14):

There is a [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org) entry which answers this question in [`perlfaq7`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-lexical-(static)-scoping%3f-Between-local()-and-my()%3f):

> **What's the difference between dynamic and lexical (static) scoping? Between `local()` and `my()`?**
>
> `local($x)` saves away the old value of the global variable `$x` and
>   assigns a new value for the duration of the subroutine which is
>   visible in other functions called from that subroutine. This is done
>   at run-time, so is called dynamic scoping. `local()` always affects
>   global variables, also called package variables or dynamic variables.
>   `my($x)` creates a new variable that is only visible in the current
>   subroutine. This is done at compile-time, so it is called lexical or
>   static scoping. `my()` always affects private variables, also called
>   lexical variables or (improperly) static(ly scoped) variables.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> sub visible {
>     print "var has value $var\n";
> }
>
> sub dynamic {
>     local $var = 'local';   # new temporary value for the still-global
>     visible();              #   variable called $var
> }
>
> sub lexical {
>     my $var = 'private';    # new private variable, $var
>     visible();              # (invisible outside of sub scope)
> }
>
> $var = 'global';
> visible();              # prints global
> dynamic();              # prints local
> lexical();              # prints global
> ```
>
> Notice how at no point does the value "private" get printed. That's
>   because `$var` only has that value within the block of the `lexical()`
>   function, and it is hidden from the called subroutine.
>
> In summary, `local()` doesn't make what you think of as private, local
>   variables. It gives a global variable a temporary value. my() is what
>   you're looking for if you want private variables.
>
> See [`Private Variables via
>   my()` in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my())
>   and [`Temporary Values via
>   local()` in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local())
>    for excruciating details.

Answer (score 9):

`my` creates a new variable. It can only be seen in the lexical scope in which it is declared.

`local` creates a temporary backup of a global variable that's restored on scope exit, but does not reduce its scope (it can still be seen globally). It does not create a new variable.

You always want to use `my` when possible, but `local` is a decent approximation when you have to deal with global variables (e.g. `$_`).

Comment: `local` also works on hash and array elements, so it's useful for temporarily changing those too.

Answer (score 8):

There are two kinds of variable scopes in Perl:

- *Global variables*: They reside in the current package, can be accessed from the outside and can have "local" values. The name can be used as a key in the "stash", the package variable hash / the symbol table.
- *Lexical variables*: They reside in the current scope (roughly delimited by curly braces). There is no symbol table that can be inspected.

Lexical variables and global variables do not interfere, there can be two different variables with the same name.

Most Perl variable magic happens with global variables. The following syntax works with global variables:

```
our $var;
$::var;
$main::var;
${'var'};
local $var;
```

but not `my $var`.

So we can write:

```
@::array = qw(a b c);
my @secondArray = @{array};
```

Which copies the arrays. We can also look up the array with a name that is stored in a variable:

```
@::array = qw(a b c);
my $name = "array";
my @secondArray = @{$name};
```

The last line abbreviates to `… = @$name`.

This is not possible with lexical vars because they do not reside in the stash.

The `local` function assigns a "local" value to a global variable (and globals only) within the current scope and in the scope of all subs that are called from within this scope ("dynamic scope").

Originally (in Perl 4) meddling with variable names and the stash was the only way to simulate references. These usages are now mostly outdated by ~2 decades as references are available (what is far safer).

Comment: The key part of your post is wrong. `local $var` is not even close equivalent to any of the others. `local $var` is the only one that changes `$var`. (`local our $var`, `local $::var`, `local $main::var`, ... would be the roughly equivalent versions.)

Comment: This is called a "soft reference", and is one of the things that `strict` keeps you from doing.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to focus on the main cases when you would use them :

- **my** should be your "default" for variables that you wish to keep restricted to a specific block. This should be most of the time
- **local** is useful if you wish to use a global variable, particular one of the special variables. For example

  ```
  local $/;                          # enable "slurp" mode
  local $_ = <$some_file_handle>;    # whole file now here
  ```

  Using local prevents your change from affecting other code (including modules you didnt write)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the difference is that `local` addressed a variable in the symbol table and `my` does not.  This is important because of how to use it:

```
local @array = @$vname;
```

That is, you're using `$vname` as a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references) (a questionable practice absent `no strict 'refs'` to tell us you know what you're doing).  Quotha:

> Only package variables (globals, even if localized) are visible to
>   symbolic references. Lexical variables (declared with my()) aren't in
>   a symbol table, and thus are invisible to this mechanism.

So symbolic references can only refer to variables in the symbol table.  Whether you declare `@a` as lexical with `my` or as global with `local`, `@$vname` only ever refers to `@main::a`.  When you say

```
local @a = qw(1 2 3);
```

, you are giving a new value to `@main::a`.  When you say

```
my @a = qw(1 2 3);
```

, you are creating a new lexical variable `@a` and giving it a value, but leaving `@main::a` undefined.  When

```
local @array = @$vname;
```

then accesses the value of `@main::a`, if finds it to be undefined and sets the value of `@array` to it.

If all that seems confusing, that's because it is.  This is why you are strongly encouraged to use `strict` and `warnings` (which would have exploded prettily on this code) and discouraged from using symbolic references unless you *really* know what you're doing.