# A simple form application with Perl

Tags: forms, perl, web-applications

I have an error while developing simple sign up form application with Perl.

This is my html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kayıt Formu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Kayıt Formu</h2>
    <form id="signup-form" action="/sample_perl_application/signup.cgi" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Ad</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="surname">Soyad</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Yaş</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="age" name="age" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sexual">Cinsiyet</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sexual" name="sexual">
                <option id="male">Bay</option>
                <option id="female">Bayan</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-default" id="save" name="save" type="submit" value="Kaydet"/>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is my perl script.

```
#!"c:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;

if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET") {
   $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}

# Split information into name/value pairs
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

foreach $pair (@pairs) { 
   ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
   $value =~ tr/+/ /;
   $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
   $FORM{$name} = $value;
}

$name = $FORM{name};
$surname = $FORM{surname};
$age = $FORM{age};
$gender = $FORM{sexual};

print CGI::header();

print $name." ".$surname." ".$age." ".$gender;
```

I have an error like this. "End of script output before headers: signup.cgi".
How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: First, you need to find out what error you got. Web server's typically send the stderr output of CGI scripts to their error log.

Comment: But I can tell you from looking at the program that it's from not declaring your variables despite telling Perl you want it to force you to do so (as you should) by using `use strict;`.

Comment: If you're using CGI.pm, why are you parsing the CGI request?!?! use `param`!

Comment: Also note that you suffer from an HTML injection bug. You are inserting text strings into HTML without properly escaping characters in need of escaping.

Comment: Use better resources to learn Perl. See https://learn.perl.org/books/ and https://learn.perl.org/first_steps/ and https://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial

Answer (score 6):

Your first mistake is to try learning Perl from the TutorialsPoint site. They really have no idea what they are talking about. Try the [Perl tutorials hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/) instead for pointers to better quality Perl tutorials.

Although CGI programs are designed to run on a web server, it's often useful to run them from a command line in order to debug them. In particular, when tracking down syntax errors, then you can use `perl -c` to see all of the problems. I put your code in a file called "testcgi" and ran the command `perl -c testcgi`. I got the following output:

```
$ perl -c testcgi 
Global symbol "$buffer" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $buffer"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "@pairs" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @pairs"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "$pair" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $pair"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 8.
Global symbol "$buffer" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $buffer"?) at testcgi line 13.
Global symbol "@pairs" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @pairs"?) at testcgi line 17.
Global symbol "$buffer" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $buffer"?) at testcgi line 17.
Global symbol "$pair" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $pair"?) at testcgi line 19.
Global symbol "@pairs" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @pairs"?) at testcgi line 19.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at testcgi line 20.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?) at testcgi line 20.
Global symbol "$pair" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $pair"?) at testcgi line 20.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?) at testcgi line 21.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?) at testcgi line 22.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 23.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at testcgi line 23.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?) at testcgi line 23.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at testcgi line 26.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 26.
Global symbol "$surname" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $surname"?) at testcgi line 27.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 27.
Global symbol "$age" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $age"?) at testcgi line 28.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 28.
Global symbol "$gender" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $gender"?) at testcgi line 29.
Global symbol "%FORM" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %FORM"?) at testcgi line 29.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at testcgi line 33.
Global symbol "$surname" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $surname"?) at testcgi line 33.
Global symbol "$age" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $age"?) at testcgi line 33.
Global symbol "$gender" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $gender"?) at testcgi line 33.
testcgi had compilation errors.
```

You can see that all of your errors are the same. You have forgotten to declare some of your variables. Your code should look like this:

```
#!"c:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;

my $buffer;

if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET") {
   $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}

# Split information into name/value pairs
my @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

my %FORM;
foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
   my ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
   $value =~ tr/+/ /;
   $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
   $FORM{$name} = $value;
}

my $name = $FORM{name};
my $surname = $FORM{surname};
my $age = $FORM{age};
my $gender = $FORM{sexual};

print CGI::header();

print $name." ".$surname." ".$age." ".$gender;
```

Notice that I have used `my` to declare the variables, not `local`. `local` is largely a hangover from Perl 4. Since Perl 5 was released over twenty years ago, `my` has been the best way to declare most variables in a Perl program. Notice, also, that I declare the variables as close as possible to where they are used.

There are some other things we can change here.

- If we import named subroutines from CGI.pm, we can make the calls to them a little cleaner by omitting the package name.
- We can use the `param` subroutine from CGI.pm to replace your buggy CGI parameter parser.
- We can use the fact that Perl variables are expanded in double-quoted strings to make your `print` statement easier to read.

Making those changes, your code reduces to this:

```
#!"c:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(param header);

my $name    = param('name');
my $surname = param('surname');
my $age     = param('age');
my $gender  = param('sexual');

# We're outputing plain text, not HTML
print header(-content_type => 'text/plain');

print "$name $surname $age $gender";
```

Doesn't that look simpler?

And you can test it from the command line:

```
$ perl testcgi2 'name=foo&surname=bar&age=18&sexual=M'
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

foo bar 18 M
```

The biggest lesson here is that if you're learning a new language, you shouldn't trust random tutorial sites on the internet. They are rarely any use. Ask people who know the language where to find good resources.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared $age, $gender, $surname variables so the script is dying.

Try verifying the script manually via 'perl -w myscript.pl' and look in your webserver error log as @ikegami suggested.

The declaration of variables in your script is a bit different from 'modern Perl' usage.

I would usually declare things with 'my', and make the declarations closer to the usage so the scope of the variables is constrained:

```
my @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach my $pair (@pairs) { 
    my($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);

my $surname = $FORM{surname};
```

Etc

Comment: That site is providing a really poor example of Perl CGI scripting. You have added 'use strict' as recommended so your script dies because you haven't declared all your variables ($gender, $surname). Please see this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603720/3575160) about why 'my' is preferred over 'local'