# How to understand local data type with respect to C++ data types?

Tags: perl

I could never clearly understand the use of local in perl except that anything defined local within a stack will be different from other existing my variables and local variable will be visible within other subroutines too.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between `my` and `local` in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129607/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-local-in-perl) which links to required reading [Seven Useful Uses of `local`](http://perl.plover.com/local.html).

Answer (score 4):

From [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29):

> A `local` just gives temporary values to
>   global (meaning package) variables. It
>   does not create a local variable. This
>   is known as dynamic scoping. Lexical
>   scoping is done with `my`, which works
>   more like C's auto declarations.

Comment: `local` is a leftover from Perl 4, which didn't have `my` or `our`.  All variables were package variables and there was no lexical scope.  Perl 5 is much better.

Answer (score 1):

`local` was the means by which the scope of variables could be reduced before `my` was introduced to the language. It's pretty much only used now in situations where lexical (`my`) variables can't be used.